# Matlab: Condition as argument or variable

Tags: matlab, conditional-operator

I have a bunch of investment strategies, implemented as functions. They shall be able to impose a variety of conditions on input data, which can all be implemented as conditions such as

```
x == 0
x ~= 17
x < 3
```

(irrelevant if those make any sense now, just for illustration)

The number of conditions is unknown, and the conditions are unkown as well, and I need to give them to the function as argument. It may safely be assumed that they all have to be fulfilled.

What is the best way to do this?

---

I've considered to use a string and execute it in the function, eg.:

```
conditions = ['==0' '~=17' '<3']
function(x, y, conditions)
```

but I find that quite cumbersome and error prone.

Could I use anonymous functions? Like

```
@ge(x)
```

and how would I provide the function handle to my function?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I may add that it is purely scientific software, i.e. every user is able to add code and thus a straight-forward way of doing this would be preferrable.

Comment: Just to be sure, the user adds the values and the conditions, and the programs just verifies those conditions are true and then proceeds to do something else?

Comment: Yes. The user, however, is a programmer using the function, so conditions could be specified in a quite technical way.

Comment: Is your number of variables also unknown? Or will it be x and y only?

Comment: Only one variable which will be checked, so bdecafs suggestions works. The user can tehn chain conditions using &&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you can use `input`:

```
a= input('my condition:')
```

input: `@(x) x>3`

then you can test `a(5)` (e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply have to apply the function (elementwise) to an input parameter `x`, then you can pass a logical vector with the results as the third argument:

`function f(x,y,v)`

`% ...does stuff like x(v), y(v), if v(i)==0...`

Then you call it as `f(x, y, x==0 | (x<3 & (x~=-17))`. In this way, the condition is checked outside the function, not inside it.

Comment: That would work, but would require the outside function to see the data. Using anonymous functions I can hide all that from my objects :)